# CoreData version migration fails in addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've got a strange bug in CoreData version migration. It crashes and I'm absolutely stumped. 
I've added two new attributes to one child entity in version 2 of my xcdatamodel and set it as current version. The code to create the persistent store coordinator looks like this:

```
 NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    self.mainModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    self.mainQueueManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [self storeCoordinatorForDB:@"MyDB.sqlite" objectModel:self.mainModel managedObjectContext:self.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)storeCoordinatorForDB:(NSString *)dbName objectModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)model managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                              inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    if (!storeURL) {
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        NSError *createError = nil;
        BOOL createSuccess = [fm createDirectoryAtURL:storeURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&createError];
        if (!createSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"Dir creation error: %@", createError);
        }
    }
    storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    NSURL *mainBundleDBURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    NSError *copyError = nil;
    BOOL copySuccess = [fm copyItemAtURL:mainBundleDBURL toURL:storeURL error:&copyError];
    if (!copySuccess) {
        NSLog(@"File copy error: %@", copyError);
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
    NSPersistentStore *ps = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{
                       NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@(YES),
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@(YES)
                             } error:&error];
    if (!ps) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error adding persistent store: %@", error);
        return nil;
    }
    return coordinator;
}
```

MyDB.sqlite is a preseeded CoreData file from the previous version of the xcdatamodel.

This results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS at an (as far as I can tell) absolutely bogus address, eg. 0x0 or 0x16)

The resulting stacktrace is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b2f95d6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   CoreData                        0x333e5274 -[NSFetchedPropertyDescription copyWithZone:] + 140
2   CoreData                        0x333d8f62 -[NSEntityDescription copyWithZone:] + 682
3   CoreData                        0x333d8e70 -[NSEntityDescription copyWithZone:] + 440
4   CoreData                        0x3340f4a8 -[NSManagedObjectModel copyWithZone:] + 340
5   CoreData                        0x3341d20e -[NSMigrationManager initWithSourceModel:destinationModel:] + 178
6   CoreData                        0x3346dc5e -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy managerForSourceModel:destinationModel:error:] + 390
7   CoreData                        0x3346f060 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 1596
8   CoreData                        0x3339235c -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 3340
9   ActorsNetwork                   0x000ba072 -[DataStore storeCoordinatorForDB:objectModel:managedObjectContext:] (DataStore.m:69)
```

Anybody any idea what's going on or helpful hints how to debug this? I've tried instruments alloctions but didn't get further.

[SOLVED] kinda. I had a fetched property definition in the model. Removing that fixed the import crash.

Comment: Please delete the app and run it again.

Comment: Did this already about 100 times. It didn't help.

Comment: please try 
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *storeMeta = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeURL error:&error];
if (storeMeta == nil || ![managedObjectModel_ isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:storeMeta]) 
{
    NSLog(@"compare successful");
}else
{
    NSLog(@"failed compare");
}
and tell result

Comment: Here is a comprehensive 2 part tutorial for core data version migration. Have a look, if you have not gone through already. [Part1](http://mipostel.com/index.php/home/66-core-data-migration-standard-part-1), [Part2](http://mipostel.com/index.php/home/70-core-data-migration-standard-migration-part-2). Hope it helps!

Comment: @geo result is "compare successful" because `[model isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:storeMeta]`returns `NO`

Comment: so you definetly have to migrate (mostly the case if you add attributes). The link of Amar (especialy part 2) should give help you. you have to open the store with the old model and migrate the old data to a new store while handling the new attributes